# Understanding step in deriving the formula of the curvature.

Tags: vectors, curvature, cross-product

Last formula on third page of the [document](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math2203/curvature.pdf):

> - Computation of $\vec{r'}(t)\times \vec{r''}(t)$ From the previous two formulas and using the properties of cross products we see that
>
> $$\vec{r'}\times \vec{r''}=\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\left(\vec{T} \times\vec{T}\right)+\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2\left(\vec{T}\times\vec{T}'\right)$$

What properties of cross products are being used here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All they're doing is distributing the product over the sum. Ie using:

\begin{equation}
    \vec{a} \times (\vec{b} + \vec{c}) = (\vec{a}\times\vec{b}) + (\vec{a}\times\vec{c})
\end{equation}

And then pulling all the scalars to the front of each term. Its pretty easy to see if you substitute in the "Computation of..." bits into $\vec{r}'\times\vec{r}''$.

Comment: So $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is a scalar?

Comment: @JaneSmith I don't see why not. $s$ is the arc length parameter (a real number which tells you how far along the curve a point is) and $t$ is any parameter which you can express $s$ as a function of. They don't make it explicit but from their notation I think $t$ is assumed to be real as well. As $s$ and $t$ are both real $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is real as well (if we assume its finite).